# How To Record Calls In Android Devices Using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, call-recording

I want to make an Android application that can record both incoming and outgoing calls in the background as a service in kotlin and at a particular time in the day, it sends all that recordings to a server by API. I had researched about it all I found is to use `Device Policy Manager` and `Telephoney Manager` but it is not much about it on the internet. So can you help me with any article, documentation, or tutorial?

Comment: Just an FYI-  an app like this may be illegal in some locations.  In the US, 19 (I think) states require you to inform the other party that a phone call may be recorded.

Comment: Hello @iamdhavalparmar

Did u find any solution?

Comment: No @Abdullqadir I had already made a comment about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution from Google as of now. Google has deprecated the feature of recording the calls in it's latest versions of Android OS. Earlier it was possible, I had tried various methods but I was only getting the silent audio when I had tried to record calls. When using Google's Phone application it only allows that application to use the microphone and other things it won't allow any other application to overpower and get that hardware access.

But there are actually two hacks to do that.

1. Build your own phone application like Truecaller and manage every call and other things from that application by doing this you can get access to managing calls on your device and you will also get the access to record the calls.
2. If your work is specific to any one mobile example like Samsung, OnePlus, etc. Then you can use any Truecaller or Google's Phone application which will store the recordings of the calls in file storage and then you can make a service to upload that call recording from that particular file location every night at 12 AM or something.

Answer (score -1):

first create MyCallRecordReceiver class

```
    class MyCallRecordReceiver(callRecord: CallRecord) : CallRecordReceiver(callRecord) {


    override fun onIncomingCallReceived(context: Context, number: String?, start: Date) {
        super.onIncomingCallReceived(context, number, start)
    }
}
```

then in MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

companion object {
    private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
}

private lateinit var callRecord: CallRecord

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  
    callRecord = CallRecord.Builder(this)
        .setLogEnable(true)
        .setRecordFileName("CallRecorderTestFile")
        .setRecordDirName("CallRecorderTest")
        .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
        .setShowSeed(true)
        .build()

}

fun StartCallRecordClick(view: View) {
    LogUtils.i(TAG, "StartCallRecordClick")
    callRecord.startCallReceiver()

}

fun StopCallRecordClick(view: View) {
    LogUtils.i(TAG, "StopCallRecordClick")
    callRecord.stopCallReceiver()

}
}
```

In addition Add it as a dependency in your app's build.gradle file

```
    allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }  
  }
}
```

and this

```
compile 'com.github.aykuttasil:CallRecorder:1.5.3'
```

Comment: What about permissions, what permssions are needed in the manifest file?

Comment: I edit post. add dependency in gradle